# Why do I get different styles on initial and reloaded pages?

Tags: support, design, new-nav

I reproducible get different styling results for the URL `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/need-answers` depending on whether I perform an initial load (enter URL and go!) or if I reload the same page (press F5).

Why is that? 
Looking into the browsers development console I failed to find a difference that might explain this.

UPDATE:

I just realize that the effect depends on how I enter the URL: 
The browsers auto completion suggests `stackoverflow.com/unanswered` when I start typing "stack", I confirm that suggestion, the page loadds as shown in the first screenshot. *Then*, when rendering has finished, the URL is changed to the final `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/need-answers`. If I enter *that* final URL directly I always get the compact view, so also upon initial load, not only on reload.

---

This is the initial view:

[image: Initial page load]

And this is the reloaded view:

[image: Reloaded page content]

---

This is a chromium browser on a KDE desktop.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with Firefox on Windows 10. There is a setting above the community bulletin board on the right hand side to switch between the condensed and regular view. It seems that your browser is not storing the setting on that page for some reason

Comment: Maybe tracking cookies are blocked?

Comment: I updated the question, gave some additional information I just realized.

Comment: @Gimby Sure, that is true. But why should that have an effect on the loaded styles?

Comment: @TinyGiant Sure, that switch does toggle the view, but it appears to be tied to an initial URL, however and whyever. I made an update to the question describing in more detail how to reproduce the effect. Maybe you could try again? Just out of interest?

Comment: because cookies are a common way to store state in a stateless web application. Just going off of Tiny Giant's observation, complete conjecture.

Comment: @Gimby But then, why the difference between a reloaded and an initially loaded view? I mean it is the same domain (hostname), so the same cookies, either blocked or accepted.

Comment: Did you clear your cache?

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes, I certainly make deep reloads and clear my cache in such situations.

Comment: Alright, so yeah, the first page loads with the expanded view automatically, then the second page loads with the condensed view. Definitely an inconsistency there. Reproducible with Firefox on Windows 10.

Comment: Btw, what is the number on the side of the review link?

Comment: @dorukayhan review queue

Comment: Hmm, Only 3 bookmarks are blackened. Something fishy there.

Comment: @BhargavRao nithing is fishy, only private.

Comment: Looks alright in Chrome; Windows 10.